# Cast to custom domain PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, casting

I am trying to create a custom domain type to force constraints for multiple tables. 
Constraints work fine, but I would also like to add custom cast that will apply lowercase before actual cast and checks.

```
CREATE DOMAIN email AS varchar(80)
  CHECK (value ~ ('^[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@' ||
                  '(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$'));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION text_as_email(text)
  RETURNS email
LANGUAGE SQL AS
$$ SELECT lower($1) :: email $$;

CREATE CAST ( text AS email )
WITH FUNCTION text_as_email(text) AS IMPLICIT;
```

Both domain and function work as expected

```
SELECT 'abc@abc.com' :: email; -- no errors
SELECT 'abc@@abc.com' :: email; -- expected error
SELECT text_as_email('ABC@abc.com'); -- no errors, returns 'abc@abc.com'
```

But cast fails to convert uppercase

```
SELECT 'ABC@abc.com' :: email; -- gives an error
```

I would appreciate any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html)

> A cast to or from a domain type currently has no effect. Casting to or from a domain uses the casts associated with its underlying type.

You are warned while creating the cast:

```
CREATE CAST ( text AS email )
WITH FUNCTION text_as_email(text) AS IMPLICIT;

WARNING:  cast will be ignored because the target data type is a domain
```

Comment: Do you know if I can create TYPE with CHECK instead of DOMAIN?

Comment: You need to extend Postgres by creating input and output functions in C to accomplish that. I would rather use domain with case-sensitive regex (`[A-Za-z0-9]`) in check.